# Uploading CSV to Sharepoint, choice column not uploading correctly

Tags: powershell, csv, sharepoint-2013

I am creating a script to upload contact information to a sharepoint list.  One of the columns (Categories) is a choice field with checkboxes for multiple selections.  I need to figure out a way to add checks to this field if I have multiple Categories in my CSV.  For example, two of the check boxes are vendor and project manager if a contact in my CSV has both i need the item in the sharepoint list to have both.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
# Setup the correct modules for SharePoint Manipulation 
if ( (Get-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null ) 
{ 
   Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
} 
$host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"


#Open SharePoint List 
$SPServer="http://SPsite/itv2"
$SPAppList="/Lists/Test CSV Upload" 
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb $SPServer 
$spData = $spWeb.GetList($spWeb.ServerRelativeURL + $SPAppList)


$InvFile="C:\Scripts\ContactUpload.csv" 
# Get Data from Inventory CSV File 
$FileExists = (Test-Path $InvFile -PathType Leaf) 
if ($FileExists) { 
   "Loading $InvFile for processing…" 
   $tblData = Import-CSV $InvFile 
} else { 
   "$InvFile not found – stopping import!" 
   exit 
}

# Loop through Applications add each one to SharePoint

"Uploading data to SharePoint…."

foreach ($row in $tblData) 
{ 
   "Adding entry for "+$row."GivenName".ToString() 
   $spItem = $spData.AddItem() 
   $spItem["First Name"] = $row."GivenName".ToString() 
   $spItem["Last Name"] = $row."Surname".ToString() 
   $spItem["Email Address"] = $row."Email1EmailAddress".ToString() 
   $spItem["Business Phone"] = $row."BusinessPhone".ToString() 
   $spItem["Mobile Phone"] = $row."MobilePhone".ToString()
   $spItem["Categories"] = $row."Categories"
   $spItem.Update() 
}

"—————" 
"Upload Complete"

$spWeb.Dispose()
$spWeb.Dispose()
```

I need to find a way to "concatenate" checks to the categories field, so that I am able to search the categories field for any of the checked boxes.  So far everything I have done will add vendor,project manager to the column, but then I am not able to filter it by vendor and have the contact come up.

Answer (score 0):

To update a multiple choice value field, you need to use a SPFieldMultiChoiceValue object. For example :

```
$choicevalues = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiChoiceValue
$choicevalues.Add("Choice 1")            
$choicevalues.Add("Choice 2")    
$list.Fields["Categories"].ParseAndSetValue($spItem,$choicevalues)
```

So you will first need to split your **$row."Categories"** variable into an array and then add each category to **$choicevalues** before updating your **Categories** field.

Hope this help!